# How to set docker back to default configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have installed docker compose and used it a little. Then decided I did not need it it. Now when I create containers by hand they are assigned a network with an ip address, gateway and other things. When I inspected older containers before i installed docker compose they do not have these network settings.

I have tried unoinstalling docker compose and reinstalling docker which did not work. Is there anything I can do? The reason I am asking is I can't link containers together because every new container is assigned an ip address and other network settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker always does that, nothing to do with compose. Compose doesn't modify your Docker installation in any way, purely connects to the daemon to run commands under the hood.

By linking containers together I'm assuming you mean just so they can communicate with each other? `--link` is deprecated for some time now in favor of `docker network ...`. Try the following:

```
$ docker network create test-net
$ docker run -d --name c1 --net test-net alpine:3.3 sleep 20000
$ docker run -it --name c2 --net test-net alpine:3.3 ping c1
```